# Consistency over availability in CAP Theorem

Tags: distributed-system, cap-theorem

In the wikipedia article on CAP Theorem(https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/CAP_theorem), it states (bold emphasis mine) "When choosing consistency over availability, the system will return an **error or a time-out** if particular information cannot be guaranteed to be up to date due to network partitioning."

If so, doesn't choosing consistency over availability mean we lose partition tolerance as well? The system might be up but if it is returning errors for all my data access, what good is it? Or, does "network partitioning" imply data partitioning as well here? In other words, if data partitioning is also implied, atleast some parts of the data are known to be up-to-date and can be returned while still satisfying the consistency requirement.

Comment: " if data partitioning is also implied, atleast some parts of the data are known to be up-to-date and can be returned while still satisfying the consistency requirement." I think the core confusion lies here. You say that some data is known to be up-to-date so can be returned....but during an arbitrary network partition, how can this be known? You may know from a god's-eye view, but the actual distributed machines can't.

Answer (score 4):

Assume you have 2 datacenters, each having a separate database and your system allows clients to connect to either 1st or 2nd datacenter. Both datacenters must be in sync, so there is a network link between them.

Now imagine that network link goes down and databases can't communicate between each other anymore (this is what a network partition means). 
What do you do now as an application developer?

You basically have 2 options:

1) Make the system available, which by CAP definition means:

> Every request received by a non-failing [database] node in the system
>   must result in a [non-error] response

Note that in our example both nodes are non-failing (they are up and running).

In other words you can allow all clients from both datacenters to write and read data but you loose consistency (see below for the definition), since writes in 1 database won't be visible in another database.

2) Make the system consistent (note that it has nothing to do with ACID consistency), which by CAP definition means linearizability, which in simple words means that if a write happend, it must by seen by the whole system (neither node must see the previous state).

In our case it meens you need to reject reads and writes from one of the datacenters, so only one datacenter becomes operational. Such system is not useless at all and you don't loose partition tolerance, since you can rereoute all your clients to the operational database.

There is a lot of confusion around the CAP theorem and I recommend that you read an excellent blog post by Martin Kleppmann that helped me understand a lot about the subject:
https://martin.kleppmann.com/2015/05/11/please-stop-calling-databases-cp-or-ap.html

Comment: If the link is down, how do you route clients from dc1(say failed DC) to dc2?

Comment: You could do it on the driver level (responsible for client -> db communication) for example, I think MongoDB driver does that.

Comment: Sorry, what I meant was, if the link is down, how will you reach the db in DC2 for clients in DC1?

Comment: The link is down between datacenters, not between clients and DC1/DC2

Comment: I appreciate your response but you don't seem to appreciate the fact that because the link is down between datacenters, clients in one DC cannot be made to connect to the db in the other DC. The only way is to move all the clients wholesale to the chosen DC or accept failure in one of the DC's. Even if you accept failure in one of the DC's the system is not fully down hence partition tolerant. This is how it is described in the link you referred to.

Comment: Sorry but I fail to understand:  

> clients in one DC cannot be made to connect to the db in the other DC. Why would that not be possible?

Comment: Because the link is down :)

Comment: I still dont see a relation, you can route the clients anyway, by connecting them directly to the DC1, the link between DC being down has no influence on that.